# What does one need to develop applications for Windows Embedded 7 Compact?

Tags: windows-embedded-compact

The question is the title.

I have downloaded http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19004. It's currently being installed. It takes care of the IDE part.

Is there anything else that I need?

And secondly, is there a start-up tutorial to create a project and a "Hello World!" app?

Answer (score 0):

you find here a couple of Win CE tutorials, they are written for the colibri modules but the getting started tutorials should help you with most of the other ARM Win CE systems.

http://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/getting-started-with-colibri-modules